# how can i change in this file "ip_local_port_range"?

Tags: 12.04, command-line

I'm new to Ubuntu I'm on `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS`  and want to change in this file but i can't

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
```

tried to use this command

```
echo "1024 65000" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
```

but after rebooting the file didn't changed ?!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the change in a running system use

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="1024 65000"
```

or

```
echo "1024 65000" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
```

---

To survive a reboot, open the configuration file

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

and add the lines below

```
# increase system IP port limits
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65000
```

After the next reboot you can see, the correct values are set.

Comment: Thanks i'm trying it now . how can i save this file ?

Comment: Save via Ctrl-O and exit via Ctrl-X

Comment: And reboot for it to take effect.

Comment: A.B.:+1.. @ThomasW. You don't need to reboot, `sudo sysctl -p` should suffice..

Comment: @heemayl yes, but only for the running system change.  The reboot survival will be the `/etc/sysctl.conf` option - when I posted my comment, the "Change in the running system" section wasn't here :)

Comment: i have a question about numbers in this file , error which i had disappeared after rebooting but when i tried to run my code after some hours , the error appeared again which mean i should change the numbers in the file ! now what are possible numbers which i can use it to prevent this problem appears again

Comment: Which numbers do you mean?

Comment: i mean this 1024    65000

Comment: And `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="1024 65000"` gives the error?

Comment: i want to increase this number but i don't know the limit of this number and why this problem appearing after executing the code ? !

Comment: i didn't execute this command, may i'll try it now and give you feedback

Comment: the problem still

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: util [ERROR] Async loop died! org.zeromq.ZMQException: Address already in use(0x62) at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.bind(Native Method) when i searched found someone changed in the ip-local to solve the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30186/discussion-between-a-b-and-user3188912).